# Reading Data from file using read function in c++

Tags: read-data

```
void fileRead()
{
    student s22;
    fstream out;
    out.open("ABC.txt",ios::in);
    while(!out.eof())
    {
        out.read((char *)&s22,sizeof(s22));
        cout<<s22.roll_no<<"\t"<<s22.name<<"\t\t"<<s22.marks<<"\t"<<endl;
    }
}
```

When I try to read data from file using **read function in C++** then it return last record 2 times.

```
Output like this:
11  Ram    70
12  Mohan  80
12  Mohan  80
```

I do not understand this problem. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: `iostream::eof` will only return true when it reads the last line of file.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine